# Polarised vs non Polarised Capacitor

Tags: capacitor, datasheet

Page 18. of http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv5606.pdf shows a polarised capacitor. In a case like this, does it really matter whether the capacitor is polarised or not, as long as the capacitance value is as specified?

Comment: I suspect this is a discrepancy between countries, industries and drafting preference. I've been taught the half curved cap symbol indicates polarization at at least 2 reputable educational organizations, and also seen seemingly all of the capacitor symbols used interchangeably, so long as documents narrow down the spec adequately one way or another. I don't blame them. I'm certainly not going to hand make a component in EAGLE because I can't find the version with the accepted Canadian symbol unless it's a legal requirement and for work. You can almost always specify with a note.

Answer (score 3):

The symbol shown in the data sheet is for a polarized capacitor, however the part that most likely would be used here is a 0.1 uF ceramic capacitor which is non-polarized. There is no reason to use a polarized capacitor in this case. Polarized capacitors are usually high valued electrolytic capacitors used for power supply bulk decoupling.

Comment: I don't understand why they would specify a polarised capacitor when there is no need.

Comment: It does not indicate it is polarized. It is just a cap symbol and it specifies in text to use ceramic. If it had a + marking then it will be polarized.

Comment: Polarized cap schematic symbol has a straight and curved line which is what is shown in the datasheet, however + sign is missing. The data sheet actually recommends 0.1 uF ceramic.

Comment: So, really it's the same as if the schematic showed two straight lines (instead of the one curve)?

Answer (score 2):

As noted by *Tony EE rocketscientist*, it's just a ceramic cap, which has no intrinsic polarity.

From your reference:
[image: Capacitor symbol]

*BTW,  the only reason I've posted this here is to include a diagram... please comment if this "answer" should be deleted.*